# Username Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I need the username to be two or more characters of `a-z`, `0-9`, all downcase. This is the current regex I am using

```
USER_REGEX = /\A[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{1,19}\z/i
```

With this regex, users are able to use uppercase charters in their username. How do I modify the current regex to avoid that?

Comment: why not just take the username the user enters - and downcase it before saving it?

Comment: How would I do that? Do I just write USER_REGEX.downcase in the following line or do I write a before_save method?

Comment: no - the regex is not the username. Also - I'd do it before validation so that you still get the validations after you've downcased it.
in a before_validation you could do: "self.username = username.downcase"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must keep the RegEx - remove the "i" from the end

```
USER_REGEX = /\A[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{1,19}\z/i
USER_REGEX = /\A[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{1,19}\z/
```

the "i" tells the RegEx to be a case-insensitive RegEx.

but you want it to be case-sensitive and only match on lowercase letters.

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression to filter for two to twenty lower-case characters or digits is

```
  /^[a-z0-9]{2,20}$/
```

which means:

1. `^` at the front of input
2. `a-z` accept lower-case 'a' through 'z'
3. `0-9` accept '0' through '9'
4. `{2,20}` accept 2 to 20 elements from preceding `[]` block
5. `$` until the end of input

You can make a regular expression case-insensitive with trailing `i`, as in your example; that appears to be the root of problem. That said, I don't know Ruby's peculiarities with respect to regular expressions.